# __dirname ceases to work when using pkg to pack my NodeJs apps

Tags: javascript, node.js

I applied the code underneath in my NodeJs application:

```
console.log(__dirname);
```

I wish to pack the application using pkg. However, where normally the path to the .js file would have been printed (let's assume it is "F:\Files\apps\my_dir", I now only get a "F:\snapshot\my_dir" (the middle part has been replaced by "snapshot".
How can I fix that?

Comment: Maybe using `path`? Something like `path.resolve(__dirname)`?

Comment: Nah. Using path.resolve(__dirname) wouldn't do.

Comment: how come? what's the reason?

Comment: Dunno why. I simply tried it out, and I got "snapshot" yet again.

Comment: Where does `snapshot` come from? Is this a configuration issue with pkg?

Comment: Well, the thing has been designed to work that way. During packaging process pkg collects project files and places them into executable called a snapshot. It might be a clever design but I certainly am not impressed by that, what with all the trouble it causes me.

Comment: So the executable is being moved and is being run elsewhere?

Comment: I think the word for it is a virtual file system. The .exe file is still there, but you don't get the correct path using __dirname. Still, got the problem solved. I can just use process.cwd() instead, and it will do the trick.

Comment: Then, may you answer the question or remove it?

Comment: Ah, my bad. In my excitement I forgot about that. Think I am going to answer it and leave the question here.

Comment: Good idea. I'm glad your issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I finally worked out the problem. We should not be using __dirname. Instead, we should do it like this:

```
const process = require('process');
console.log(process.cwd())
```

Comment: Nope guys, cwd is a bad idea. What if you want to dynamically require a json that is next to the executable but not in your cwd?